# Unrecognized selector error with performSelector: method

Tags: objective-c, selector, unrecognized-selector, performselector

I call

`[delegate addText:button.titleLabel.text withSelector:@selector(addElement:) fromKeyboard:self.name]`

which corresponds to

```
- (void)addText:(NSString *)text withSelector:(SEL)selectorName fromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {

   [tempData performSelector:@selector(selectorName) withObject:text];

}
```

However, when I call the perform selector method on tempData, I get the error. When I replace selectorName with (addElement:) it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only write like that

```
[tempData performSelector:selectorName withObject:text];
```

it is already a selector so you dont need to write @selectr(...)

Answer (score 3):

@selector(selectorName)
you forget :
@selector(selectorName:)

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. I've tried addElement/selectorName, addElement:/selectorName:, addElement:/selectorName, and addElement/selectorName:

Comment: @divol, maybe not the OP's problem, but it helped in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a bit of confusion around the `@selector()` construct here:

The `@selector(selectorName)` is a literal for the selector with the name inside the braces, 
`selectorName` in this case (much like `"selectorName"` is a literal for the C string inside the quotes. This means that you are trying to send selector named  `selectorName` to the `tempData` object, which fails.

If you want to pass in the selector to send by name, use the `NSSelectorFromString()` function:

```
- (void)addText:(NSString *)text withSelector:(NSString *)selectorName fromKeyboard:(NSString *)name {
 [tempData performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(selectorName) withObject:text];
}
```

It might be a good idea to make sure the receiver responds to the selector in this case by using `-respondsToSelector:`